# How to add a comma to the end of a list efficiently?

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of horizontal names that is too long to open in excel. It's 90,000 names long. I need to add a comma after each name to put into my program. I tried find/replace but it freezes up my computer and crashes. Is there a clever way I can get a comma at the end of each name? My options to work with are python and excel thanks.

Comment: How are the names separated? I wrote a little program to generate such a file and tried a search/replace using Emacs. Worked fine without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: Are you going to provide us with an example of this data?

Comment: Add the code you have and what kind of data the function you want should take and return

Comment: they are just seperated by a space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually had a Python list, say `names`, then `','.join(names)` would make into a string with a comma between each name and the following one (if you need one at the end as well, just use `+ ','` to append one more comma to the result).

Even though you say you have "a list" I suspect you actually have *a string* instead, for example in a file, where the names are separated by...?  You don't tell us, and therefore force us to guess.  For example, if they're separated by line-ends (one name per line), your life is easiest:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
  result = ','.join(f)
```

(again, supplement this with a `+ ','` after the join if you need that, of course).  That's because separation by line-ends is the normal default behavior for a text file, of course.

If the separator is something different, you'll have to read the file's contents as a string (with `f.read()`) and split it up appropriately then join it up again with commas.

For example, if the separator is a tab character:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
  result = ','.join(f.read().split('\t'))
```

As you see, it's not so much worse;-).

Comment: My guess is that it's space or tab separated. Only because he said: "horizontal list"

Comment: Yeah its just sepearated by spaces

Comment: @Robert, then split by space (or, if by "spaces" you mean "arbitrary whitespace" instead, just call split without arguments, which will split the string by arbitrary sequences of whitespace -- spaces, tabs, and so on).

Comment: Thanks. Working now! Great help Alex.